# Select values from a list that are not in a table

Tags: mysql

I have a list of ids:

```
(1, 2, 3, 6, 7)
```

And a table:

```
id | anothercolumn
------------------
 1 | NULL
 2 | foo
 4 | bar
 5 | NULL
 6 | NULL
```

I want to retrieve the values from my list which are not ids of my table.

Expected result:

```
3, 7
```

#### SELECT without FROM

I tried something like this:

```
SELECT i
WHERE i IN (1, 2, 3, 6, 7)
AND i NOT IN (SELECT id FROM mytable);
```

But this is not a valid MySQL query (a `FROM` is required).

#### UNION

There is also this possibility:

```
SELECT i
FROM (
    SELECT 1 AS i
    UNION SELECT 2
    UNION SELECT 3
    UNION SELECT 6
    UNION SELECT 7 ) AS mylistofids
LEFT JOIN mytable
ON mytable.id = i
WHERE mytable.id IS NULL;
```

This works, but if my list of ids becomes bigger, the query will soon be huge ...

#### Temporary Table

I can also create a temporary table for my list of ids:

```
CREATE TEMPORARY TABLE mylistofids (
    i INT
);

INSERT INTO mylistofids (i) VALUES (1), (2), (3), (6), (7);
```

Then use it in a `LEFT JOIN`:

```
SELECT i
FROM mylistofids
LEFT JOIN mytable
ON mytable.id = i
WHERE mytable.id IS NULL;
```

This works too, but in my case, I don't have the rights to create a table (temporary or not).

Do you see a way to solve this problem in the nicest way possible?

Comment: Without a temporary table you probably have to solve it in the calling code. Once the list gets to big the DBMS will hit limits on the IN statement. Also IN statements do not add new keys to results, so the **SELECT without FROM** (even with a FROM) will always fail. The UNION version will work, but will be slow for larger numbers.

Answer (score 25):

A temp table is the best solution, but if not possible then you can fudge a temp table by selecting constants and unioning them together.

Using this solution you can do the following:-

```
SELECT i
FROM 
(
    SELECT 1 AS i UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7
) AS mylistofids 
LEFT JOIN mytable
ON mytable.id = i
WHERE mytable.id IS NULL;
```

You can also generate a massive range of numbers (assuming that you are dealing with integer ids) by cross joining ranges of numbers. Then just pick the ones that are in the IN clause:-

```
SELECT i
FROM 
(
    SELECT units.i + tens.i * 10 + hundreds.i * 100 + thousands.i * 1000 + tensthousands.i * 10000 AS i
    FROM (SELECT 1 AS i UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0 ) AS units
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS i UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0 ) AS tens
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS i UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0 ) AS hundreds
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS i UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0 ) AS thousands
    CROSS JOIN (SELECT 1 AS i UNION SELECT 2 UNION SELECT 3 UNION SELECT 4 UNION SELECT 5 UNION SELECT 6 UNION SELECT 7 UNION SELECT 8 UNION SELECT 9 UNION SELECT 0 ) AS tensthousands
) AS mylistofids 
LEFT JOIN mytable
ON mytable.id = i
WHERE mylistofids.i IN (1, 2, 3, 6, 7)
AND mytable.id IS NULL;
```

Comment: With the first bit there is no difference, but you can expand it to use the 2nd solution.

Comment: I suspect the performances to be horrible, but nice idea in the case of a big list (instead of union-ing every item of the list one by one) ! I'll try to benchmark this solution tomorrow.

Comment: I suspect you are right, but if you were cheeky and had an existing table with a continuous sequence of id fields you could use that!