# mysql find where in not exist, result not exist result only

Tags: mysql

```
+----+-------+
| id | name  |
+----+-------+
|  1 | John  |
|  2 | Peter |
|  3 | Devi  |
|  4 | Susan |
|  5 | April |
+----+-------+
```

below is my sql query:-

```
select * from users where id in (1,3,6,9,10);
```

How can I get the result to know that 6,9,10 is not exist?

My goal is want to 6,9,10 via sql statement, is it possible?

Comment: Consider handling display issues in application code

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32461970/select-values-from-a-list-that-are-not-in-a-table